# no linux command found after installing jdk1.8 on redhat distribution?

Tags: linux, redhat

After i installed correctly jdk1.8.0 on my redhat distribution and restarted my computer, no linux command is found anymore! the last step i did in the installation of jdk1.8.0 was to write these variables in /etc/environment as it's mentionned in a link which by the way i followed to install jdk1.8.0 :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_121
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin
```

when the day after i started my machine, i do "dir" or "ls" or "vi" or whatever else;

```
bash dir: command not found
bash vi: command not found
```

I read in the net that i've messed a path, but no solution is suggested. so how could i fix this problem ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide `echo $PATH` output.
Hotfix: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin`

Also these outputs:
`cat ~/.bash_profile`
`cat ~/.profile`
`cat ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Any $ variables referenced in /etc/environment statements are not expanded. It may be better to alter PATH in your .bashrc . https://askubuntu.com/questions/150789/difference-between-bash-bashrc-and-etc-environment-file

Comment: @the.Legend echo $Path output : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin:/root/bin For cat ~/.bash_profile output : -bash: cat : command not found

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Sorry i am newbie to linux. How to alter PATH in my .bashrc?

Comment: @the.Legend i executed the Hotfix line (export PATH=...) you wrote and then it's fixed. i execute the cat commands and all the others. But i didn't understand what was the problem! Thanks for helping.

Comment: @drissrais $PATH is the variable where bash looks for programs. This is one of Linux fundamentals. If you want to work with Linux you must learn this topic. Please read this article for understanding how variables work: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables